# service iptables stop - Failed to stop iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not loaded

Tags: linux, iptables

I can't stop iptables. I get the following error message:

```
[root@dot38 pick]# service iptables stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  iptables.service
Failed to stop iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not loaded.
```

Comment: what does `sudo journalctl -u iptables` say?

Comment: It says 'no entries'.

Comment: Well, you've seemingly got something different which manages firewall rules then.

Comment: There's a bunch of rules in iptables. I can add new rules to it but I can't stop it.